# Issues with find and replace Excel C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, excel

Hey im having issues with my code that dont really want to work is has been working with Word interop but when I change it to Excel it keeps returning me an error message in Private void CreateWordDocument (Excel.document Adoc and excelapp.document.open)

```
    private void FindAndReplace(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application wordApp, object findText, object replaceWithText)
    {
        object matchCase = true;
        object matchWholeWord = true;
        object matchWildCards = false;
        object matchSoundLike = false;
        object nmatchAllForms = false;
        object forward = true;
        object format = false;
        object matchKashida = false;
        object matchDiactitics = false;
        object matchAlefHamza = false;
        object matchControl = false;
        object read_only = false;
        object visible = true;
        object replace = 2;
        object wrap = 1;

        wordApp.Selection.Find.Execute(ref findText,
                    ref matchCase, ref matchWholeWord,
                    ref matchWildCards, ref matchSoundLike,
                    ref nmatchAllForms, ref forward,
                    ref wrap, ref format, ref replaceWithText,
                    ref replace, ref matchKashida,
                    ref matchDiactitics, ref matchAlefHamza,
                    ref matchControl);
    }



    string pathImage = null;
    private void CreateWordDocument(object filename, object savaAs, object image)
    {
        List<int> processesbeforegen = getRunningProcesses();
        object missing = Missing.Value;


        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

        Excel.Document aDoc = null;

        if (File.Exists((string)filename))
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            object readOnly = false; //default
            object isVisible = false;

            excelApp.Visible = false;

            aDoc = excelApp.Document.Open(ref filename, ref missing, ref readOnly,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            aDoc.Activate();

            //Find and replace:
            this.FindAndReplace(excelApp, "$$firstname$$", txtFirstName.Text);


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("file dose not exist.");
            return;
        }

        //Save as: filename
        aDoc.SaveAs2(ref savaAs, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        //Close Document:
        //aDoc.Close(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

        MessageBox.Show("File created.");
        List<int> processesaftergen = getRunningProcesses();
        killProcesses(processesbeforegen, processesaftergen);
    }


    public List<int> getRunningProcesses()
    {
        List<int> ProcessIDs = new List<int>();
        //here we're going to get a list of all running processes on
        //the computer
        foreach (Process clsProcess in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id == clsProcess.Id)
                continue;
            if (clsProcess.ProcessName.Contains("WINEXCEL"))
            {
                ProcessIDs.Add(clsProcess.Id);
            }
        }
        return ProcessIDs;
    }


    private void killProcesses(List<int> processesbeforegen, List<int> processesaftergen)
    {
        foreach (int pidafter in processesaftergen)
        {
            bool processfound = false;
            foreach (int pidbefore in processesbeforegen)
            {
                if (pidafter == pidbefore)
                {
                    processfound = true;
                }
            }

            if (processfound == false)
            {
                Process clsProcess = Process.GetProcessById(pidafter);
                clsProcess.Kill();
            }
        }
    }
    //Méthode Enabled Controles:
    private void tEnabled(bool state)
    {
        txtFirstName.Enabled = state;


    }
    //Load the Template Document:
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            tFilename.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            tEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            CreateWordDocument(tFilename.Text, saveFileDialog1.FileName, pathImage);
            tEnabled(false);
            //printDocument1.DocumentName = SaveDoc.FileName;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hey. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and try to overhaul your question in a manner that makes sure we know exactly what you are trying to accomplish, and where you got stuck. To be more specific: "Issues" and "Error Messages" don't help to much. At least tell what the exceptions said and where they got raised exactly.

Comment: Off-topic, but .NET 4+ makes `ref missing` obsolete

Answer (score 0):

Word Interop and Excel Interop are very different. You can't just change 'Word' into 'Excel'. You'll probably will have to select the worksheet, define a range of cells, loop through the range, etc... Plenty of snippets on google.

Comment: Ahh thank for the time guys i suspected that i would have to do something like this